# paragraph text and input box inline in html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get paragraph text and input box inline in css but couldnt figure out the way.Please have a look at below html code

```
<div id="parap"> 
    <p id="para" class="aa" ng-repeat="colname in insertsqldata">
        <span id="ss"> {{colname}} </span>  
        <input class="aa" id={{colname}}> 
    </p> 
</div>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/aoc8ccb8/

Comment: Why not use a table?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid: you use the same ID multiple times.

Comment: its form and table wont be much helpful..

Comment: Why won't it help much?

Comment: You know you can have a table inside a form, right?

Comment: To be fair, tables aren't needed here and for the sake of learning CSS should be avoided in my opinion. They're not the way forward for anything other than some very specific use cases.

Comment: @SamHH Yes tabular data. Which this kinda is

Comment: i will have to rewrite lots of javascript if i use table i guess

Comment: A form consisting essentially of inputs with labels does not qualify as tabular data unless you abuse the definition of the word tabular.

Comment: have a look at fiidle shell http://fiddle.jshell.net/aoc8ccb8/

Comment: @SamHH Care to share a link to said definition and tell me what is being violated? Not saying you are wrong, but now I am genuinely curious where you get that from.

Comment: @PeeHaa My mistake, I meant "data" at the end. This is not data.

Comment: @SamHH Now I am even more confused what you mean :P How is that not data?

Comment: @PeeHaa Haha. Well, tables are meant for displaying data. That is, the sort of stuff you'd stick into a spreadsheet. It is not supposed to be used for layout/stylistic purposes which is how it would be being used in this case. This is something that should be approached with CSS and is arguably easier with CSS.

Comment: My suggestion is to use your browser dev tools and have a look at how other websites do this. It's a pretty common layout so it shouldn't be to hard to find what you are looking for, I suggest looking at the Bootstrap or Foundation docs to find what css they use to achieve the layouts in their forms.

Comment: @SamHH And what happens when your spreadsheet has a single row of data and you turn it on its side?  All of the field labels are in one column and all of the field values are in another column.  The fact that you only have one set/row of data does not make it not tabular.

Comment: @SamHH FWIW I also polled the people in the html/css room about the above. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/conversation/form-vs-tabular-data-part-i and http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/conversation/form-vs-tabular-data-part-ii :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `#ss` and `input` to `display: inline-block` and adjust the input's margin-left as desired.

Comment: Could you be more specific? If I enter your fiddle and adjust as I said to (be sure to remove the margin-left entirely whilst testing) it works.

Comment: can u share the link.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this a table, a display attribute, float attribute, or a vertical-align.  I prefer the vertical-align then you don't have to mess with margins.

So you could do something like;

```
<style type='text/css'>
  form
     {
       display:inline;
       float:left;
     }
 </style>
```

and then do the vertical-align attributes on the css properties of the individual id [parap].

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to set the **id=#ss** also you to adjust the **margin from left** as per the requirement